# Twitter iOS App: Can I Control Notifications on All Accounts I'm Logged Into?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, twitter

With the recent changes in Twitter, you can not tweet to more than one account using third party apps such as HootSuite. I use Twitter to tweet from several accounts on my iPhone. I only want to receive notifications from my Twitter account. Can this be done without shutting off the notifications for the other account owners?